# Key press with Input.GetKey returns true multiple times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm facing a problem in `unity3d` when activating and de-activating an object. I want to enable the object when I press a key, and disable it when I press it again.

I think my code is fine. But it's doesn't working correctly. When I press the button first time, object is activated, then immediately deactivates sometimes key press work fine sometimes not. I think it's because of `Update()` function, it runs on every frame.I don't know what I do.

Code:

```
public class A : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject invSystem;
    [SerializeField]
    bool buttonCheck;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.P))
        {

            if (!buttonCheck)
            {
                invSystem.SetActive(true);
                buttonCheck = true;
            }

            else
            {
                invSystem.SetActive(false);
                buttonCheck = false;
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  [`GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) which will only be true only once in a frame until relased and pressed again. [`GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) whill return true while it is held down. This will make it to be triggered more than once making your `if` statement to be true and executed multiple times in a frame.

`if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.P))` should be replaced with  `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))`